# ScaledImageButton not displaying image

Tags: codenameone

First attempt

```
    Image myImage = getResources().getImage("mypic.jpg");
    ScaleImageButton imageButton = new ScaleImageButton(myImage);
```

Second attempt was to explicitly set the style

```
    Image myImage = getResources().getImage("mypic.jpg");
    ScaleImageButton imageButton = new ScaleImageButton(myImage);
    imageButton.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);
```

// BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL gave the same results.
I can see the encoded image in the debugger's watch but it does not appear on the button
Using the generic button the image displays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that could be happening here so you need to go through this with the process of elimination.

First: is the image "good". Place a breakpoint and inspect the image, does it have a non-zero width/height?

Inspect the component itself in the component inspector. Does it have a non-zero size so the image will have space to show within?.

If the answer to the second one is no then we need to look into the way in which the component was added to the UI. Which layout, preferred size etc.

Comment: The image does have a non-zero size.I used a different skin and the image now displays.  Thanks though.

Comment: I suggest checking the size in the layout. You might be hiding the issue by switching a skin and might need to adjust layout/scrolling behavior so the component has more space allocated to it